# Change variable under partial derivation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Hy all, i will take $x\in \mathbb R$ and $y\in\mathbb R^n$.

I wondering about what happen if i have $\partial_{x}u(e^{-x},y)$ and i do variable change $s=e^{-x}$. How is change $\partial_{x}u(e^{-x},y)$?

The new function is just $\partial_{s}u(s,y)$? or i need take $-\log(s)=x$ and do the calculation
$$ds=-e^{-x}dx\leftrightarrow -\frac{ds}{s}=dx$$ and work more, sorry i am really stuck and i do not know how continuous, please can you help me?

$\partial_{x}u(e^{-x},y)=-\frac{\partial_s u(s,y)}{s}?$

Comment: $$\partial_{x}u(e^{-x},y)=\partial_{s}u(s,y)\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\partial_{y}u(s,y)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=-e^{-x}\partial_{s}u(s,y)=-e^{-x}u_1'(e^{-x},y)$$

Comment: @Ricky   thank you so much, the last term is zero right?

Comment: @weymarandres That's right.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thank you!!